# Update content in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uipickerview

I have a pickerView and I want it to update every time the user picks a new row. I have 2 arrays: 1 for the first component - "categorie", and another for the second component - "subCat". I then have a MutableArray which I add objects to in 'didSelectRow' called - "sub".

After I add objects to 'sub', I put it in an NSLog, and it output what I expected it to. The problem is when I add 'sub' to 'subCat', then update the picker view, it gives me an error.

(When I commented out "subCat = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:sub];" it worked flawlessly.)

I'm a beginner as you can probably tell, so please don't be too harsh on me.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        return [categorie count];
    }
    else {
        return [subCat count];
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        return categorie[row];
    }
    else
    {
        return subCat[row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    subCat = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    sub = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (id key in values) {
        if ([key isEqualToString:rowSelection]) {
            [sub addObject:[values valueForKey:key]];
        }
    }
    subCat = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sub];
    [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Error:

```
 -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7febfbd7d9b0
2015-01-16 12:32:06.163 MyApp[1254:34938] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7febfbd7d9b0'
```

Comment: How you declared and initializing `sub` ?

Comment: sub = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (id key in values) {
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"Key"]) {
                [sub addObject:[values valueForKey:key]];
            }
        }

Comment: Now that you posted that code, I take back what I said. BTW - update your question with that code. It's too hard to read in a comment.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that your `sub` array contains arrays and not strings. This means that your dictionary values are arrays.

Comment: You are right. My dictionary values are arrays. Is that bad?

Comment: It's only bad because you add the arrays to the `sub` array. So you have an array of arrays. But the picker view expects an array of strings. Perhaps you want to add the contents of each array to the `sub` array.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are *a* problem, but they're not necessarily what's causing the crash:

```
subCat = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // Here you have created a new array.
subCat = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sub]; // Here you replace that new array you created with another new array.
```

This construction is probably not what you want:

```
sub = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id key in values) {
  if ([key isEqualToString:@"Key"]) {
    [sub addObject:[values valueForKey:key]];
  }
}
```

It is operationally the same as this:

```
[sub addObject:values[@"Key"]];
```

Based on the error you're seeing, the object that you have stored into `sub` is actually an `NSArray` and you are later calling `length` on it. Instead, try this:

```
sub = values[@"Key"];
```

or

```
[sub addObjectsFromArray:values[@"Key"]];
```

Comment: What do you mean @"Key"? key is an id, not a string?

Comment: You're the one calling `isEqualToString` (a method from `NSString`) on it.. I was just following your lead. I'm not sure that `id` in Objective-C means what you think it means.